# Executing dependencies in order using Scala Futures

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

I have a task runner as follows

```
package taskman

import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

final class Task private (
    desc: String,
    dependencies: Seq[Task] = Seq.empty[Task],
    body: => Unit
) {

  def run(): Future[Unit] = Future {
//    println(s"Executing dependencies for $desc")
    Future
      .sequence(dependencies.map(_.run()))
      .map { _ => body }
  }
}

object Task {
  def task(desc: String, dependencies: Seq[Task] = List.empty[Task])(
      body: => Unit
  ): Task =
    new Task(desc, dependencies, body)
}

object taskTest extends App {
  import Task._

  val boilWater = task("Boil water") {
    println("Boiling water ")
  }

  val boilMilk = task("Boil milk") {
    println("Boiling milk")
  }

  val mixWaterAndMilk =
    task("Mix milk and water", Seq(boilWater, boilMilk)) {
      println("Mixing milk and water")
    }

  val addCoffeePowder = task("Add coffee powder", Seq(mixWaterAndMilk)) {
    println("Adding coffee powder")
  }

  val addSugar = task("Add sugar", Seq(addCoffeePowder)) {
    println("Adding sugar")
  }

  val makeCoffee = task("Make coffee", Seq(addSugar)) {
    println("Coffee is ready to serve")
  }

  Await.result(makeCoffee.run, 10.seconds)
}
```

I expect the dependencies to run in parallel and after finishing then execute the body. But I am always getting this in the wrong order.

The expected order is as follows

Boiling water
Boiling milk
Mixing milk and water
Adding coffee powder
Adding sugar
Coffee is ready to serve

Boiling milk and water can be done in any order but the rest of the things should be executed in order. I am executing the body on Future.sequence.map {}, but still the order isn't correct. There is something wrong with this code for sure but I am not able to figgure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the spurious extra `Future` in `run`.

```
def run(): Future[Unit] = Future { // <-- Not required
  Future
    .sequence(dependencies.map(_.run()))
    .map { _ => body }
}
```

Removing it fixes the problem:

```
def run(): Future[Unit] = 
  Future
    .sequence(dependencies.map(_.run()))
    .map { _ => body }
```

Comment: `Future.sequence(dependencies.map(_.run()))` could _(should?)_ be replaced wih `Future.traverse(dependencies)(_.run())`

Comment: tried the traverse and it is working, actually, both are working, why do you recommend traverse over sequence